# Nodejs connecting database in every request

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, database

In My app.js i have this piece of code.

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    req.db = db;
    next();
});
```

So basically attaching the db in every request.

I would like to know the best way to access db from other js files
If any one can provide some samples, it will be great help for me

Comment: Create middleware that connects to the DB, then just require that middleware where you need, it will be cached and just keep one connection open

Comment: Learn about how [Modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules) work. `db` must be a module. You simply `require` it in your other js files

Comment: ok so existing code in app.js is var mongo = require('mongodb');
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('localhost:27017/table'); So you mean to say i need to use the same code in all the js files where i need to use the db. Will this affect the loading time of the js, can this be the best way ?

Comment: @JerilKuruvila No. Checkout how [module.exports](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports) work. If you only want `db` just export that and `require` it in other files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node Modules are cached, thus if you made a module with:

**db.js**

```
//...
module.exports=monk('localhost:27017/table');
```

and when you need it in another file, you can just call:

```
var db=require('db.js');
```

Only the first time you call it, the `monk` function will be run. The object will be cached, and the same object will be returned in any subsequent `require`.